# Programs/Scripts for plotting penrose diagrams

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, conformal-field-theory

What programs do people generally use to plot penrose diagrams? I need to plot some simple ones for the dS and AdS and Schwarzschild metric and my hand drawn ones dont look very good.

Comment: I draw them on Mathematica

Comment: You can draw them with TikZ. See [this TeX SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99124/how-to-draw-penrose-diagrams-with-tikz).

Comment: ↑ is much better.